# Need to replace string in file2 that matches first column of file1 with second column of file1

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

So, if the title didn't make sense, here's what I'm trying to do:

I have file1:

```
66.115.135.84:123.123.123.1
66.115.135.85:123.123.123.2
66.115.135.86:123.123.123.3
66.115.135.87:123.123.123.4
66.115.135.88:123.123.123.5
66.115.135.89:123.123.123.6
66.115.135.90:123.123.123.7
66.115.135.91:123.123.123.8
66.115.135.92:123.123.123.9
66.115.135.93:123.123.123.10
66.115.135.94:123.123.123.11
66.115.135.95:123.123.123.12
66.115.135.96:123.123.123.13
66.115.135.97:123.123.123.14
```

As you can see, it's ip addresses, separated by a ":"

File2 is basically an apache virtual host entry, or httpd.conf file.  It doesn't really matter.  Just know that file2 contains the ip addresses from the first column of file1 somewhere in there.  And they need to be replaced by the second column of file1.

For some reason, this simple problem has left me bewildered.  I've tried some pretty gnarly things, but keep getting stuck.

I know I can separate them using awk, and i know i could pipe that into sed to act on file2.

But I can't seem to wrap my head around the best way to "map" column 1 to column 2 so that this can actually happen.

I'm willing to use perl, or ruby, or python, or really any method of achieving this, and I would very much like a brief explanation of how you are able to solve this.

Please ask for any clarification, and I'll be glad to supply it.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id use perl. Lets call it `mapper.pl`. Takes map file as an arg, and then maps `stdin` to `stdout`. So you use it like this

```
perl mapper.pl file1 < file2 > file2.new
```

The `mapper.pl` program is something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Prototypes
sub readMap($);

# Main program
{
    if( scalar(@ARGV) != 1 )
    {
        die "usage: mapper.pl mapfile";
    }
    my %map = readMap( $ARGV[0] );
    while( my $line = <STDIN> )
    {
        foreach my $old ( keys(%map) )
        {
            my $old_re = $old;
            # Escape metacharacters
            $old_re =~ s/\W/\\$&/g;
            $line =~ s/$old_re/$map{$old}/g;
        }
        print $line;
    }
} # END main

sub readMap($)
{
    my $mapname = $_[0];
    my %map;
    open( MAPFILE, "<$mapname" ) || die "open($mapname): $!";
    while( my $line = <MAPFILE> )
    {
        if( $line =~ /^\s*([^:]+):(.*?)\s*$/ )
        {
            $map{$1} = $2;
        }
        else
        {
            warn "Invalid line: $line";
        }
    }
    close( MAPFILE );
    return( %map );
} # END readMap
```

Comment: wow.  i tested it and it worked perfectly.  i'm going to have to mess around with this until i understand it completely, as i don't use perl often.  I really appreciate this.

Comment: You can use `/\Q$old\E/...` instead of trying to escape all alphanumeric characters in a copied variable. Or `quotemeta`.

Comment: @TLP, thanks mate. Learn something new every day. Frustrating too, I've been doing it the dodgey way for almost 10 years now. Serves me right for just skimming man pages when learning the language. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sodved I know what you mean. SO is great for learning things you didn't know you needed to know. =)

Answer (score 2):

Read the IP pairs from file1 into a hash, e.g. `$ip{$old} = $new`. I assume there are no duplicate IPs. Go through file2 looking for IPs, and use a regex such as:

```
s#($IPregex)# $ip{$1} // $1 #eg;
```

Code something like:

```
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', "file1";
my %ip;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split /:/, $_, 2;
    $ip{$key} = $val;
}

open $fh, '<', "file2";
my $rx = qr/\b\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\b/;

while (<$fh>) {
    s#($rx)# $ip{$1} // $1 #eg;
    print;
}
```

Redirect to output file as needed. Might need a better regex for the IP.

Comment: i didnt see this one.  this is great, and very readable.  thanks to everyone whose code i'm going to "steal" and repurpose ;)

Comment: @Kevin You're not stealing, Kevin. If I was worried about people stealing my code, I wouldn't have posted it on the Internet. =P Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl  -ne '/(.*):(.*)/; (exists $ips{$1}) ? (print "$ips{$1}\n") : ($ips{$1} = $2);' f1 f2
```

This loops over file f1 then file f2. It splits them on the ':' character and if we haven't seen the first half before, stick it in the hash. If we have seen the first half before, print the value we stored in the hash.

Comment: i couldnt get this one to work just yet, but i see where its going, awesome stuff!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e "s:$(sed -e ':a;$!N;s/\n/:g;s:/g;ta' file1):" file2
```

The inner `sed` creates a multi-expression regex for the outer sed to apply to file2..
To securely update your original file insitu, you can pipe the output to ir via `sponge` (from package [moreutils](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/moreutils/)).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
  FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    split($0, ary, /:/)
    map[ary[0]] = ary[1]
    next
  }
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ($i in map)
        $i = map[$i]
    }
    print
  }
' file1 file2 > file2.new
```

Comment: i had something like this going in awk at first, couldnt get mine to work.  Thanks!  Who says awk is archaic and hard to understand... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the great answers!

I was inspired by them to create a ruby version:  (it could use some work/reduction, it's not very rubyesque yet, but it works)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#replaces old ips for new ips in virt file
@orig_ips=Array.new
@new_ips=Array.new
File.open("/home/kevin/scripts/ruby_scripts/test.virt", "r").each do |line|
  if line =~ /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/
    @orig_ips.push(line.split.last.chop)
  end
end

File.open("/home/kevin/scripts/ruby_scripts/new_ip_list", "r").each do |line|
  @new_ips.push(line.split.last)
end

f = File.open("/home/kevin/scripts/ruby_scripts/test.virt")
working_file = f.read
for count in 0..@orig_ips.count - 1  do
  old = @orig_ips[count]
  new = @new_ips[count]
  working_file.gsub!(old, new)
end
puts working_file
```

Comment: Instead of `File.open(filename).each {}` you can say `File.foreach(filename) {}`. Use `chomp` instead of `chop` (it's safer because it only removed newline chars). You don't chomp on the new_ip_list file? If you `File.open` without a block, you should close it when you're done. You can say `File.read(filename)` instead of `f=File.open(filename); f.read; f.close`

Comment: actually, i goofed on this, i forgot, i changed the input file before i posted this, with this, i was using a new_ips file that just had a line by lime ip address list, and acting directly on the virtual host file.  so i was actually chopping off the ">".  Realllllly dirty, it has since evolved, and you're absolutely right about closing the file.  And the foreach i just saved away in the memory banks, thx!